# How to run Python code before `site` module is imported?

Tags: python, python-3.x, initialization, cpython

Is there a way to execute Python code before the `site` module is imported?

---

In case it matters, I'm asking because I'm running an embedded Python interpreter via `Py_Initialize`, and I'd like to configure the Python environment using Python code, however it's important this happens before the `site` module is imported since the changes impact how it initializes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`Py_NoSiteFlag`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_NoSiteFlag) to suppress loading of `site.py` while initializing Python interpreter. `site` could be loaded later-on manually.

Here is a minimal example:

```c
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_NoSiteFlag = 1; /* Suppress 'import site' */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; print('site' in sys.modules)\n");

    //There are no site-packages in path:
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(sys.path)\n");

    // do what must be done
    // ....

    //now, import site manually,
    //call site.main(), so site-packages are added to sys.path:
    PyRun_SimpleString("import site; site.main()");

    //now, site-packages are in path:
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(sys.path)\n");

    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        exit(120);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When running the resulting executable, one sees that `site` isn't loaded in `Py_Initialize` (first printed line is `False`) and is loaded later. We also need to call `site.main()` explicitly for site-packages to be put into `sys.path`.

Comment: As long as the environment for importing `site` is similar enough that this doesn't introduce compatibility issues, than this is fine.

Comment: @ideasman42 you actually needs to call `site.main()` explicitly, so the site-packages are put into the `sys.path` (see also my update).